# Do Microsoft Band web tiles support TLS 1.2

Tags: microsoft-band

Seems like the Web Tile Creation tool doesn't support TLS 1.2

Does anyone know if the Health App supports it?

**Clarification**
Using the creation tool at: https://developer.microsofthealth.com/WebTile You cannot specify a datasource that is using TLS 1.2

Doing so causes an Invalid URL message.

I'm wondering if it's only a limitation of the tool above or also a challenge in the health app.

Comment: What about the tool doesn't work, the site itself, using a data source for a Tile that uses TLS 1.2, etc.?  Can you describe or provide an example of what you were trying to do?

Comment: Phill Hoff: I updated my question with a little more information.

Comment: Thanks.  What data source were you trying to use (if you can say)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't...I turned TLS 1.0 back on for now anyway so you wouldn't be able to see the fail. It was failing until I turned TLS 1.0 on and then it worked. I'll be leaving it in place for the holiday but if you want I can reach out next week and show you. I'll email you via your blog with my contact info in case you want to connect.

Comment: To determine whether the TLS 1.2 issue only affects the creation tool, you could turn on TLS 1.2 after you have created your Web Tile and see if it can be installed and run successfully on phones. If it does work on the phones, then that would indicate that it is just the creation tool that is running in an environment where it cannot connect using TLS 1.2.

Comment: Jeff Kelley - I turned TLS 1.0 off this afternoon leaving only TLS 1.2 and it does still work on the phone. So the app seems ok. Additionally the tile creation tool referenced in the question is once again reporting an invalid URL. So it does appear that the creation tool environment does not support TLS 1.2